# VBA Excel Choose File - When cancel is clicked it clears the textbox

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I have a spreadsheet with a form on it. On that form there is a textbox that contains a file path which could be pre-populated from a cell on the sheet. But the user can choose to browse for another file. When they are browsing they have an option of "Open" or "Cancel". The open button works fine and populates the textbox, but if they choose cancel it clears the textbox if it is already populated. How can I stop the textbox being cleared?

I have narrowed it down to this block of code where it is happening:

```
Function GetFileName()

    Set MyFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With MyFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show <> -1 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        GetFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Assuming the textbox is named `TextBox1`, could you check for this in `TextBox1_Change()` and process it accordingly?

Comment: You have narrowed it down too much. The showed code neither populates nor clears a text box. It calls a file dialog and then does nothing with the selected file. It simply ends without returning something, regardless of whether there is a file selected or cancel is clicked.

Comment: @AxelRichter I Missed out GetFileName = .SelectedItems(1) just above the End With. I Know where It was going wrong now beceause the GetFileName was being set to "" which was then populating in my textbox. I now test it before it populates the textbox. Thanks for responding though guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done the trick. Making sure the file name has a value before populating the textbox

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()

    Dim sFileName As String

    sFileName = GetFileName()

    If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Value = sFileName
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFileName()

    Set MyFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With MyFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show <> -1 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        GetFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

End Function
```